# why this code cannot find a match record, while it does exist

Tags: java, if-statement

when "detele" key word has been detected, the program is designed to search a matched name in an arraylist, and return an index value to indicate the index in the arraylist, then the record will be deleted. Now in the arraylist, one record has name "Testing One", but the program cannot find that name. I tested it, the program returned -1 to indicate there is no such record. But when I use println(personList.get(0).getName()), the output shows there is a space like " Testing One".

The outputs are:

-1

" Testing One"

The name does not exist, delete failed!

```
else if(words[0].equalsIgnoreCase("delete"))
{
    if(words.length<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of record you want to delete");
    }
    else
    {   
        String name = "";
        if(Functions.nameValidation(words[1]))
        {
            for(int i = 2; i < words.length; i++)
            {
                name = words[1] + " " + words[i];
            }
            if(Functions.nameValidation(name))
            {
               int index = Functions.searchPeopleByName(personList, name);
               System.out.println(index);
               System.out.println(personList.get(0).getName())
                if(index>=0)
                {
                    personList.remove(index);
                    FileIO.outData(personList, outputFileName);
                }
                else
                {
                       System.out.println("The name does not exist, please check again");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The name is invalid, please check again!!!");
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The name is invalid, please check again");
        }
    }           
}

public static boolean nameValidation(String name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        if ((!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i))) && (name.codePointAt(i) != 32))/*space*/ {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static int searchPeopleByName(ArrayList<Person> personList, String name)
{
    for(int i=0; i<personList.size();i++)
    {
        if(personList.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Please use the correct spelling for words like 'you', 'your' & 'please'.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help.

Comment: Your `nameValidation` checks if `A-Z` or `a-z` or `space` exists at least once in String. Take a pencil and piece of paper and try to check how `nameValidation` works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You return true is any character is valid.  I suspect to wanted to return false if any character is invalid.

Comment: but the character only be valid is belonging to "A-Z" or "a-z" or "space". Any other character like *&^%%$$ should return false. Correct?

Comment: Correct but you want to change your logic to ALL characters must be valid instead of ANY character must be valid.